# Orthogonal eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, eigenvalue, parity

I have to show that two eigenfunctions of an electron in a 1 dimensional infinite square well with different parity and different quantum numbers are orthogonal. I am attempting this by integrating the product of the two eigenfunctions

$\psi_n=A_n \sin(\frac{nx\pi}{a})$,

with $n_1$ and $n_2$, which are not the same. Am I doing this the right way or is there any different methods I should do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for two eigenfunctions to be orthogonal is that their inner product is zero. In Dirac notation this would mean: $$\langle \psi_n|\psi_m\rangle=0\quad m\neq n\tag{1},$$ and in wave function notation (as you have written $\psi_n(x)=\langle x|\psi_n\rangle$ in your question) this becomes: $$\langle \psi_n|\psi_m\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi_n(x)^*\psi_m(x)dx=0 \quad m\neq n\tag{2}.$$ You can from here verify that the eigenstates of the infinite square well Hamiltonian corresponding to different values of $n$ (the $\psi_n$) are orthogonal.

You could also infer this from the fact that since $\hat H$ is Hermitian its eigenfunctions corresponding to different eigenvalues are necessarily orthogonal. Since each energy eigenfunction of the $1D$-infinite square well has a different energy value they must be pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: In my course we still have not come across the inner product in quantum mechanics, so would it be viable to actually integrate the eigenfunctions?

Comment: @user728655 That is the definition of the inner product on the space of wavefunctions.

Comment: @user728655, I think that either you missed something, or the lecturer took something for granted as already known. It is not possible to talk of orthogonality without first defining the inner product.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more slick, more mathematical way, of approaching the problem, by using the general theorems that eigenvalues of a Hermitian operator are real and that eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal. In this case the result is a trivial corollary. However, I do not think the question would be asked if this is what was intended.

I think in the context of the question you are doing this the right way. You can use standard trigonometric identities to carry out the integration, and it is almost certain that this is what it is intended you should do. I think the question is a didactic exercise intended to lead you towards the theorems. It is not intended that you should use the theorems to prove the result.

To prove the theorems, suppose that $|k\rangle$ and $|l\rangle$ are eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator $O$ with eigenvalues $k$ and $l$ respectively,
$$ O|k\rangle = k |k\rangle$$
Then
$$ \langle k|O|k\rangle = k \langle k|k\rangle$$
It follows at once (since $\langle l|k\rangle =\overline{\langle k|l\rangle} $) that Hermitian operators have real eigenvalues.

Act, with $\langle l|$,
$$ \langle l|O|k\rangle = k \langle l|k\rangle$$

Take the complex conjugate, using the fact that $O$ is Hermitian
$$ \langle k|O|l\rangle = k \langle k|l\rangle.$$
We also have
$$ O|l\rangle = l |l\rangle.$$
Then
$$ \langle k|O|l\rangle = l \langle k|l\rangle.$$
Subtract and obtain
$$ 0 = (k-l) \langle k|l\rangle.$$
So, if $k$ and $l$ are distinct, $|k\rangle$ and $|l\rangle$ are orthogonal.